# Make doubleclick Home act as Home with Autohotkey, and single click as PrintScreen

Tags: autohotkey

I want my Home-button (single click) to act as PrintScreen, and double clicking the Home-button act as Home. I can't get it to work.

Beneath the code I used prior that acts the other way around (doubleclicking makes it act as PrintScreen, one time as, well Home). That does work.

Can anybody tell me what I need to change in the script?

```
~Home::
if (A_PriorHotKey = "~Home" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
{
   Send, {PrintScreen}
  ;Msgbox,Double press detected.
}
Sleep 0
KeyWait Home
return
```

Comment: Remove `Sleep 0` and `KeyWait Home`

Comment: That does not do the trick. I want my Home-button (single click) to act as PrintScreen, and double clicking the Home-button act as Home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't passthrough the hotkey with `~`, use `$` to indicate you may send the hotkey you override in its handler. Check `A_PriorKey` instead of `A_PriorHotKey` so that it filters out quickly typed sequences of non-hotkeyed keypressed like <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>.

This sends <kbd>Home</kbd> on doublepress BUT it'll also send <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> before the doublepress is detected:

```c
Home::send % A_PriorKey="Home" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400 ? "{Home}" : "{PrintScreen}"
```

And this solves the above problem by delaying <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> for 400ms:

```c
$Home::
    if (A_PriorKey = "Home" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400) {
        settimer, sendPrintScreen, off
        send {Home}
    } else {
        settimer, sendPrintScreen, 400
    }
    return

sendPrintScreen:
    settimer, sendPrintScreen, off
    if (A_PriorKey = "Home")
        send {PrintScreen}
    return
```

Comment: There's also an example of detecting single/double/triple-presses in the [SetTimer documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples).